# Geometric interpretation of FINDING eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a pretty good idea for the geometric interpretation of what eigenvectors are I think.

When following the steps:
\begin{equation}
Ax = \lambda x
\\
(A - \lambda I)x = 0 
\end{equation}

Obviously it works because subtracting $\lambda x$ from $Ax$ will only be zero when they are equal.  However, I don't quite intuitively understand.

Subtracting by $\lambda$ in $R^2$ seems to move $\hat i $ in the x-direction by $\lambda$ and $\hat j $ in the y-direction by $\lambda$ until they are on the same line thus meaning $det(A - \lambda I) = 0 $.  I still don't completely understand why this gives us the eigenvector of our original transformation $A$ though.

Hope this has not been asked before, and makes sense. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Minor typo: the second equation should be $(A-\lambda I) x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're trying to understand is, in a general sense, why is it that for matrices $A,B$ and a vector $x$, we have
$$
Ax = Bx \implies (A - B)x = 0.
$$
In order to understand why this should hold in a "geometric" sense, we need a geometric interpretation of the transformation associated with $A-B$ in relation to the transformations associated with $A$ and $B$. Note that the transformation $A-B$ can be thought of as the following process:

1. Apply $A$ to get $Ax$,
2. Apply $B$ to get $Bx$,
3. Subtract these to get $Ax - Bx$.

The result of applying $(A-B)$ to $x$ is this difference $Ax - Bx$.

With that in mind, consider what happens when $B = \lambda I$.  The result $Ax - \lambda x$ is zero if and only if $Ax$ and $\lambda x$ are the same vector. That is, $(A - \lambda I)x = 0$ if and only if $A$ scales the vector $x$ by a factor of $\lambda$.

Comment: I think you're right that's what I meant to ask.
Ax = Bx is certainly possible for some x, where A not equal to B.  However it is never possible for all x, where A not equal to B.
It is also possible that Ax = Bx is never true for some A and B, where A and B are rotations.  I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this in the right way still, but every individual statement you made seems to make sense.

Comment: I guess Ax = Bx -> (A-B)x = 0 solutions are the null space of (A-B) will only have non-zero solutions when det(A-B) = 0, but what does that have to do with A and B.

Comment: @JosephGutstadt I'm not quite sure what you're asking with that second comment. One thing you can say is that the solution space $(A - B)x = 0$ is the largest subspace on which the transformations associated with $A$ and $B$ have the same effect; maybe that's the kind of answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The operator $\lambda I$ scales every vector by $\lambda$. You want to find the particular vectors $x$ that $A$ does that to (that's the definition of an eigenvalue/eigenvector pair). So you solve for $x$ in
$$
Ax = \lambda Ix .
$$

In operator terms that's
$$
(A - \lambda I)x = 0.
$$

One way to find out whether that equation has any solutions other than the $0$ vector is to look at the determinant of $A-\lambda I$.